# Bokeh World Map and Coloring Waterbodies

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, matplotlib-basemap

Is there an equivalent way in Bokeh to Basemap's `drawmapboundary` where you can specify certain colors? See the first example [here](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# setup Lambert Conformal basemap.
m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,projection='lcc',
            resolution='c',lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=50,lon_0=-107.)
# draw coastlines.
m.drawcoastlines()
# draw a boundary around the map, fill the background.
# this background will end up being the ocean color, since
# the continents will be drawn on top.
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
# fill continents, set lake color same as ocean color.
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
plt.show()
```

I would like to fill waterbodies (e.g., oceans) with the color "aqua". I'm able to generate a black-and-white world map, but how do I color oceans specifically?

I'm using the JSON file for countries from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json), and then loading it with `GeoJSONDataSource`.

```
import bokeh.plotting as bkp
import bokeh.models as bkm

filename = "test.html"
tools = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,previewsave"

with open("./countries.geo.json", "r") as f:
    countries = bkm.GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=f.read())

p = bkp.figure(width=1000, height=600, tools=tools, title='World Countries', x_axis_label='Longitude', y_axis_label='Latitude')
p.x_range = bkm.Range1d(start=-180, end=180)
p.y_range = bkm.Range1d(start=-90, end=90)
p.patches("xs", "ys", color="white", line_color="black", source=countries)

bkp.output_file(filename)
bkp.save(p, filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out by looking at what `drawmapboundary` does. Just need to set the background color. :)

```
import bokeh.plotting as bkp
import bokeh.models as bkm

filename = "test.html"
tools = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,previewsave"

with open("./countries.geo.json", "r") as f:
    countries = bkm.GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=f.read())

p = bkp.figure(width=1000, height=600, tools=tools, title='World Countries', x_axis_label='Longitude', y_axis_label='Latitude')
p.background_fill_color = "aqua"
p.x_range = bkm.Range1d(start=-180, end=180)
p.y_range = bkm.Range1d(start=-90, end=90)
p.patches("xs", "ys", color="white", line_color="black", source=countries)

bkp.output_file(filename)
bkp.save(p, filename)
```